# Syspro Connection Test fails through FlowGear DropPoint

Tags: flowgear

When testing my newly-configured Syspro connection to work through a DropPoint, I get the following error:

(Syspro 1.0.0.2) Message queue client closed!

What am I missing?

EDIT:

More info:
Now that I'm testing a previously-working (about a week ago) SQL Watcher on the same DropPoint I'm getting an error:

The Node SqlWatcher (v2.1.0.4) could not be initialized.

Comment: What version of the DropPoint are you using? Check under the DropPoint's pane for the Client Version

Comment: It is version 3.1.0.0